# Facebook: migrate an app from one Business Manager to another

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-business-sdk

Is it possible to migrate an app from a business manager to another?

We develop an app that required business verification and we associate it with a sandbox business manager, instead of the real one.
Now we want to correct this error and associate the app with to real business manager, but there is an error because the app is owned by another business manager.
I saw that in the wrong business manager it is possibile to remove an app, but what will happens? Will the app stop to work? What's the right migration procedure to avoid service interruption?